# Inserting new row into table with user session of an job interview application

Tags: php, mysql

I have a job website, and inside there is a page that lists open jobs by date.
A logged in user of my website clicks on available dates for application (from a dynamic list sorted by date).
There are currently 2 tables, users and jobs, which are fixed.

Once a user selects a date, I am wondering what the best way is to take column data from both tables and insert it into a new table I created called 'applications'.

There are 2 columns for this 'applications' table: user ID (pertaining to specific user) and job ID (pertaining to the job that user clicked on).

I am new to this and am having trouble with 2 parts:
1. Collecting the current user's ID with the session
2. Collecting the job ID from my dynamic list by posting it.

My dynamic list for upcoming 7 jobs looks like this:

```
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs 
WHERE status = '1' 
ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 7");
$jobCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($jobCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $id = $row["id"];
         $job_date = $row["date"];
         $pay = $row["pay"];
         $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="17%" valign="top"><a href="job.php?id=' . $id . '"></a></td>
      <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $job_date . '<br />
        Status' . $pay . '<br />
        <a href="reserve_job.php?id=' . $id . '">Apply Here</a></td>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Is this all of your code?  It looks like there's an unclosed while loop and if statement.

Comment: Yes I do have closing tags for both the if and while loop.  I need to link each <tr> output (next 7 applications) with a php/mysql call that INSERTs the respective job ID and the current user ID into a 'applications' table.

Answer (score 0):

Change, this LOC and let me know then is this what you are looking for.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

To

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am a little confused how I can insert the row within this while loop ($id) in another php command, say apply.php, as well as with the users ID.